# Build new list from two lists, keep order the same, with equal representation as much as possible

Tags: python

I have two lists, `a` and `b`. I need to build a new list, `c` using elements from `a` and `b`.

Requirements:

1. `c` has a maximum length, *n*.
2. I want, as much as possible, to have equal representation from `a` and `b`
3. `a` elements must precede `b` elements in the new list
4. `a` and `b` elements should be in the same order they were in originally

For example, if:

```
a=['a1','a2','a3']
b=['b1']
n=3
```

`c` should be `['a1','a2','b1']`

My question is, "How to do this in Python?".

Comment: Take the first n/2 items from a and the first n/2 items from b and put them together

Comment: @MichaelBianconi how would that make sure that the length `n` is not exceeded?

Comment: Because n/2+n/2 == n

Comment: What is your question? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define `mid` to be the midway point (with more elements from `a` if `n` is odd) and take the first `mid` elements from `a` and `n-mid` elements from `b`.

```
import math
mid = min(math.ceil(n/2), len(a))

c = a[:mid] + b[0:(n-mid)]
```

I added the `min(of math.ceil(n/2) and len(a))` because it is possible `a` does not have n/2 elements